# Visual Studio Code: different linters in different projects

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code 1.4.0.  I am involved in two different projects, one of which uses jslint and the other which uses eslint.  I have both installed and working, but the only way I can figure out how to switch between the two is to open up settings.json, edit and reload.  I tried disabling both and then enabling them in jsconfig.json.  E.g., in settings.json:

```
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite the default settings
{
    "jslint.enable": false,
    "eslint.enable": false
}
```

Then in jsconfig.json:

```
"eslint.enable": false,
"jslint.enable": true
```

This doesn't work (it doesn't actually change settings and looking at the documentation, it doesn't appear to be the intended use of jsconfig.json anyway).  Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Are the linters installed globally or locally?

Comment: At the time, they were installed both locally and globally.  I have since stopped using VS Code, so things have probably progressed from when I asked the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't found the solution yet - you can customize vscode at the project-scope level using Workspace settings. Workspace settings are stored inside your workspace in a .vscode folder and only apply when the workspace is opened.

You can access workspace setting either using the **File (Code on Mac) → Preferences** menu or using the **Command Palette** (press <kbd>F1</kbd>). Settings defined on this scope override the user scope.

You can configure your linters (or other extensions) and then commit `.vscode/settings.json` to your repository.